# VisJS Network is not centered

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, vis.js

I am trying to create a vis js network. This is how the graph should look like

[image]
 Here is the code as seen on the page source

```
<script type="text/javascript">

             var options = {
              width: '1000px',
              height: '600px',
              nodes: {
              font: {
                multi: true,
                bold: {
                  mod: '',
                  color: '#940A0A'
                    }
                 }
               }
              };

              // create an array with nodes
              var devNodes = new vis.DataSet(<array-of-nodes>);

              // create an array with edges
              var devEdges = new vis.DataSet(<array-of-edges>);
              var devData = {
                nodes: devNodes,
                edges: devEdges
              };

              // create a network
              var devContainer = document.getElementById('networkDiv');
              var devNetwork = new vis.Network(devContainer, devData, options);
              devNetwork.on( 'select', function(properties) {
                var ids = properties.nodes;
                console.log('clicked nodes:', ids[0]);
                });
        </script>
```

and here is the corresponding html

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" id="devPanel">
                    <div class="panel-heading" id="devHeading">DEV</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="networkDiv"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Now, I have to include this graph as part of a table. However, now the network is not rendered in the center of the div

[image]

here is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

             var options = {
              width: '1000px',
              height: '600px',
              nodes: {
              font: {
                multi: true,
                bold: {
                  mod: '',
                  color: '#940A0A'
                    }
                 }
               }
              };

              // create an array with nodes
              var devNodes = new vis.DataSet(<array-of-nodes>);

              // create an array with edges
              var devEdges = new vis.DataSet(<array-of-edges>);
              var devData = {
                nodes: devNodes,
                edges: devEdges
              };

              // create a network
              var devContainer = document.getElementById('networkDiv');
              var devNetwork = new vis.Network(devContainer, devData, options);
              devNetwork.on( 'select', function(properties) {
                var ids = properties.nodes;
                console.log('clicked nodes:', ids[0]);
                });
        </script>
```

here is the corresponding html

```
<tr>
                <td> val1 </td>
                <td> val2 </td>
                <td>

                    <p class="bg-success">

                val3  </p></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="blah">val4</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-info" data-target="#networkPanel">val5 button</button>
                </td>

            </tr>
<tr>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary panel-collapse collapse" id="networkPanel">
                        <div class="panel-heading">val2</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="networkDiv"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

So, in the second case, why does the network get rendered in the top left corner? How can i ensure that the network is always rendered in the iddle of the div?

Comment: It seems like problem is with the collapse functionality. It is not because of the table implementation.

Comment: oh, you are right. i did not know that collapse could do that. is there a fix?

Comment: Has a hack. Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this hack for show/hide network canvas and this will solve the positioning problem of the network. I don't know whether is this the post suitable way or not. But this will do the trick. For the show hide functionality we can use

```
.hide {
 position: absolute !important;
 top: -9999px !important;
 left: -9999px !important;
}
```

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/)

class instead of using `display:none;`. You can use `toggleClass` method to toggle between `hide` class and remove collapse functionality. Working demo can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rexzing/v6rcxgu3/12/).

Comment: thanks! it worked :) just one more thing. i tried `$("#networkPanel").toggleClass("hide");` just after i create the network, but if i do that, the original problem appears again! if i dont do that, the graph is displayed correctly but the panel is shown from the start (subsequent toggles work correctly). I would really like to hide the panel initially

Comment: also, with your suggestion, i cant move around the nodes

Comment: I will look for better solution without these issues.

Comment: You can put `hide` class to the parent div initially. Then try to toggle.

Comment: which parent div?